# How to change the value only in specific parameter in retrofit android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gson, retrofit2

I have url

https://pixabay.com/api/?key=12973823-c1d0c689a2cb0af7706951221&q=dogs&image_type=photo

In the above url, q=query Here is where I need to change the data to pass the parameter.

But I am clueless how to pass the parameter only in q whereas all others after q are fixed.

I can only apply as static one but I don't know how to change the q by passing the edittext field as string to that parameter q=

```
public class RetrofitService {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://pixabay.com/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    //can't change to private. Since the use case of create service is in another class
    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }


}  



  public interface ImageApiInterface {
    @GET("?key=12973823-c1d0c689a2cb0af7706951221&q=dogs&image_type=photo")
    Call<MyImages> getMovieDetails();
}
```

Here I am passing static string as dog, which is working but I need to change this as input parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API Interface will be like this:

```
public interface ImageApiInterface {
  String PIXABAY_URL = "https://pixabay.com/";

  @GET("api/?key=12973823-c1d0c689a2cb0af7706951221&image_type=photo")
  Call<PixabayResponse> getMovieDetails(@Query("q") String query);
}
```

Create Model Class Pixabay

```
public class Pixabay implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;

@SerializedName("largeImageURL")
@Expose
private String imageUrl;

@SerializedName("user_id")
@Expose
private String userId;


public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
```

}

Create Class PixabayResponse

```
public class PixabayResponse implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("totalHits")
@Expose
private String totalHits;

@SerializedName("hits")
@Expose
private List<Pixabay> pixabayList;

public List<Pixabay> getPixabayList() {
    return pixabayList;
}

public void setPixabayList(List<Pixabay> pixabayList) {
    this.pixabayList = pixabayList;
}

public String getTotalHits() {
    return totalHits;
}

public void setTotalHits(String totalHits) {
    this.totalHits = totalHits;
}
```

}

Now Create a method in your activity:

```
private void callPixabayImages(String query){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Api.PIXABAY_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
            .build();

    Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

    Call<PixabayResponse> call = api.getMovieDetails(query);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<PixabayResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PixabayResponse> call, Response<PixabayResponse> response) {
            List<Pixabay> imagesList = response.body().getPixabayList();

            for (int i=0; i<imagesList.size(); i++){
                Pixabay data = imagesList.get(i);
                System.out.println("ID# "+ data.getId());
                System.out.println("UserID: "+ data.getUserId());
                System.out.println("ImageURL: "+ data.getImageUrl());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PixabayResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+ t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

Now Call this method like below:

```
callPixabayImages("dogs");
```

Comment: I am getting 404 response

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this.

```
 public interface ImageApiInterface {
    @GET("?key=12973823-c1d0c689a2cb0af7706951221&q={query}&image_type=photo")
    Call<MyImages> getMovieDetails(@Path("query") String query);
}
```